# Keep original image size AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I have UIImageView in profile where I download some image from the server. Everything is fine, and image is presented. When I want to reupload image from that imageView, everytime quality of image is worsest.

When I am downloading image, I am using: `[self.profileViewImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.user.profileImageURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profileImage"]];`

I upload image as NSData: `NSData *profileImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(uploadImage)`;

How can I save image original size?

Comment: I don't think this is related to your AFNetworking download process. Maybe you can use "UIImageJPEGRepresentation" instead of "UIImagePNGRepresentation" which has a "compressionQuality" setting?

Comment: I tried that, same issue...

Comment: How is declared the uploadImage variable?

Comment: UIImage *uploadImage = [self.companyViewProfileImage.image];
    NSData *profileImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(uploadImage);

Answer (score -1):

I usually use the AFNetworking

```
- (BOOL)appendPartWithFileURL:(NSURL *)fileURL
                         name:(NSString *)name
                        error:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error
```

function in the AFHTTPRequestOperation request block to upload a file without converting it to NSData. This way I don't have any quality loss.

Maybe it could help you.

Comment: Yes, this is good idea, but I have user interaction, where user can change that image to some local image...

Comment: Then save it in a file meanwhile?